# Ansible, line module not saving JSON data to file correctly

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that sets the variable "certData" which is an array of dictionaries.
This is what "certData" looks like:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "cn": "node1.corp.com",
            "expires": "2020-11-05T15:20:18+00:00",
            "id": 705,
            "serial": "111"
        },
        {
            "cn": "node2.corp.com",
            "expires": "2020-11-05T15:20:28+00:00",
            "id": 728,
            "serial": "222"
        },
        {
            "cn": "node3.corp.com",
            "expires": "2020-10-28T19:37:29+00:00",
            "id": 670,
            "serial": "333"
        },
        {
            "cn": "node4.corp.com",
            "expires": "2021-04-04T09:55:08+00:00",
            "id": 1163,
            "serial": "444"
        },
        {
            "cn": "node5.corp.com",
            "expires": "2020-11-05T15:20:22+00:00",
            "id": 715,
            "serial": "555"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a play that is taking the data from "certData" and saving it a file called cert_expiring.json like this:

```
- name: Testing jinja
      lineinfile:
        dest: "./cert_expiring.json"
        line: |-
          {
          "devices": [{
              "items": {
          {%- for i in certData -%}
          {{ "" if loop.first else "," }}
                "{{ i.id }}": "{{ i.cn }}"
          {%- endfor %}
            
              }
          }]
          }
        state: present
        create: yes
```

The playbook runs successfully but gives this warning:

```
[WARNING]: The value {'devices': [{'items': {'705': 'node1.corp.com', '715': 'node5.corp.com', '670': 'node3.corp.com', '728': 'node2.corp.com', '1163':
'node4.corp.com'}}]} (type dict) in a string field was converted to u"{'devices': [{'items': {'705': 'node1.corp.com', '715': 'node5.corp.com', '670':
'node3.corp.com', '728': 'node2.corp.com', '1163': 'node4.corp.com'}}]}" (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not
change.
```

The data from the warning is exactly how it gets printed to the "cert_expiring.json" file with single quotes.

certs_expiring.json:

```
{'devices': [{'items': {'705': 'node1.corp.com', '715': 'node5.corp.com', '670': 'node3.corp.com', '728': 'node2.corp.com', '1163': 'node4.corp.com'}}]}
```

But, when I load the contents of the "cert_expiring.json" back into a variable (expired_certs2) and print it, it prints properly:

```
 - name: Store file contents into variable
   include_vars:
     file: cert_expiring.json
     name: expired_certs2
    
 - name: Print expired_certs2 variable.
   debug:
     msg: "{{ expired_certs2 | json_query('devices[*].items') }}"
```

```
TASK [Print expired_certs2 variable.] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "1163": "DUKEISEC12.corp.cox.com",
            "670": "sage.stg.cox.com",
            "705": "btnrssmoloch01.corp.cox.com",
            "715": "elmwssmoloch01.corp.cox.com",
            "728": "rnkessmoloch01.corp.cox.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried single quoting the Jinja code like this but it doesn't help:

```
- name: Testing jinja
      lineinfile:
        dest: "./cert_expiring.json"
        line: |-
          '{
          "devices": [{
              "items": {
          {%- for i in certData -%}
          {{ "" if loop.first else "," }}
                "{{ i.id }}": "{{ i.cn }}"
          {%- endfor %}
            
              }
          }]
          }'
        state: present
        create: yes
```

Also, tried using double quotes with no luck.

How can I get the data to print to the "cert_expiring.json" file in proper json format?

Answer (score 2):

Q: *"**How can I get the data to print to the "cert_expiring.json" file in proper JSON format?**"*

A: Use filter *to_json*, e.g.

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: cert_expiring.json
        name: expired_certs2
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ expired_certs2 | to_json }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: '{"devices": [{"item": {"705": "node1.corp.com", "728": "node2.corp.com", "670": "node3.corp.com", "1163": "node4.corp.com", "715": "node5.corp.com"}}]}'
```

The query

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ expired_certs2.devices | json_query('[].item') | to_json }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: '[{"705": "node1.corp.com", "728": "node2.corp.com", "670": "node3.corp.com", "1163": "node4.corp.com", "715": "node5.corp.com"}]'
```

---

It's possible to simplify the content, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        devices: "{{ devices | default([]) +
                     [{'item': certData | items2dict(key_name='id', value_name='cn')}] }}"
    - copy:
        dest: cert_expiring.json
        content: >
          {"devices": {{ devices | to_json }} }
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat cert_expiring.json
{"devices": [{"item": {"705": "node1.corp.com", "728": "node2.corp.com", "670": "node3.corp.com", "1163": "node4.corp.com", "715": "node5.corp.com"}}] }
```

Comment: when i apply the "to_json" filter and print expired_certs2 my output prints like yours but all the double quotes are excaped ("msg": "{\"devices\": [{\"items\": {\"705\":...).

when i try to print using `json_query('[].items') | to_json`, this prints the same with escaped double quotes.

when taking your simplified approach it works and creates the cert_expiring.json file with the proper syntax....btw **devices** should be in double quotes correct?

Comment: This depends on the callback plugin. See ``ansible-doc -t callback -l``. I use ``yaml`` callback plugin. The escaped quotation might be a result of the ``json`` callback plugin. The callback plugin is responsible for printing the data. The Jinja2 templating is not influenced by callback plugins.

Comment: You're right. JSON standard requires double quotes. I've fixed the answer. Thank you.