# Ansible: How to write in JSON format with lineinfile module?

Tags: ansible

I want to create a file that shows the execution progress and what is being done when I run tasks. Now I want to generate a JSON format when I have done it through `local_action` and `lineinfile`.

This is my playbook

```yaml
- name: The module that Set the progress and details
  block:
    - name: Set the progress and details
      shell: echo "10"
      register: progress_result
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Set the progress and details
      shell: echo "update docker script"
      register: message_result
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Save progress
      delegate_to: localhost
      local_action:
        module: lineinfile
        path: "{{playbook_dir}}/scheduler/plan.yaml"
        regexp: "progress:"
        line: "progress:{{progress_result.stdout}},step:{{message_result.stdout}}"
        create: yes
```

The current results of operation is

```
# cat scheduler/plan.yaml 
progress:10,step:update docker script
```

But I would like to have the results in JSON format

```json
{"progress":"10","step":"update docker script"}
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

That's nearly impossible with `lineinfile`, because your regexp and inserts must be valid json.

Instead of, you must re-read your file (lookup), parse `from_json`, append the json data and write it back `to_json`.

I'm interested why someone is tracking the ansible task process manually?

Comment: So how does this thing re-read the file as you said to complete the parsing? Is there an example

Answer (score 0):

... some background information to the other given answer here.

To write out a line with double quotes within you could use an approach like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    progress_result:
      stdout:  10

    message_result:
      stdout: update

  tasks:

  - name: Save progress
    lineinfile:
      path: test.txt
      regexp: "progress:"
      line: '"progress":"{{ progress_result.stdout }}","step":"{{ message_result.stdout }}"'
      create: yes
```

will result into an output of

```json
"progress":"10","step":"update"
```

This will not apply for the curly braces (`{`,`}`).

Since your line to write does contain variables which need to be templated it will not be possible to use just `!unsafe`. Instead you could use `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` to prevent templating on certain parts of the string.

```yaml
      line: '{% raw %}{{% endraw %}"progress":"{{ progress_result.stdout }}","step":"{{ message_result.stdout }}{% raw %}"}{% endraw %}'
```

resulting into an output of

```json
{'progress': '10', 'step': 'update'}
```

but which is then not valid JSON.

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to stop Ansible Jinja2 string interpolation (templating)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74003446/6771046)
- [How to write tick marks and brackets with Ansible `lineinfile` module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73818041/6771046)

---

**How to proceed further?**

You may have a look into questions like

- [Add a new key-value to a JSON file using Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50796673/6771046)

and as already mentioned in the other given answer here, as well

- [Ansible: `lineinfile` module not saving JSON data to file correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67679628/6771046)

as they provide possible solutions.